# iterate xml and modify values in java

Tags: java, xml, spring, xml-parsing, domparser

I have an xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ns0:studentDetails>xmlns:e = "http://XXXXXXXXX/school/" category = "school">
<ns0:studentName>John</ns0:studentName>
<ns0:studentCode>3376</ns0:studentCode>
<ns0:studentCGPA>8.5</ns0:studentCGPA>
</ns0:studentDetails>
```

I would like to iterate over xml and replace the old values with the new values.
I'm passing file path to method from my test case

```
import org.junit.Test;
public class MyTest {
@Test
void testXmlModify(){
 String filePath = "C:/Users/john/myxml.xml";
 DOMParserModify.xmlModify(filePath);
 }
}
```

As I'm new to domparser, I have tried sevaral approaches but not fulfill my requirement.

```
public class DOMParserModify{

 String filePath = "C:/Users/john/myxml.xml";
File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

xmlModify() method is as below:

```
public void xmlModify(Document doc) {
        NodeList student = doc.getElementsByTagName("studentDetails");
        Element element = null;

        for(int i=0; i<stu.getLength();i++){
            element = (Element) student.item(i);
            String name = element.getElementsByTagName("StudentName").item(0).getNodeValue();
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("John")){

                element.setAttribute("Smith"));
            }
             String code = code.getElementsByTagName("studentCOde").item(0).getNodeValue();

if(code.equalsIgnoreCase("3376")){

                element.setAttribute("7244"));
            }
         String cgpa = cgpa.getElementsByTagName("studentCGPA").item(0).getNodeValue();

if(cgpa.equalsIgnoreCase("8.5")){

                element.setAttribute("9.2"));
            }

    }
}
```

updated values should be saved in same xml file i.e., myxml.xml
my final xml should look like below with the updated vales.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ns0:studentDetails>xmlns:e = "http://XXXXXXXXX/school/" category = "school">
<ns0:studentName>Smith</ns0:studentName>
<ns0:studentCode>7244</ns0:statusCode>
<ns0:studentCGPA>9.2</ns0:statusCGPA>
</ns0:studentDetails>
```

Could you please correct me where I'm gone wrong.
Thanks